# Getting Resource from strings

Tags: java, android, string, concatenation

I've got many resources with names based on a pattern:

```
R.drawable.small_house_red  
R.drawable.small_house_blue  
R.drawable.big_house_black  
R.drawable.small_tree_red
```

I've got 3 strings: size, type, color. I can put all required resources to map, and get them by concated string but is it possible to get them without manually entering all combinations to the map?

Comment: Could you clearify where you have all the resouces name?  If you have a file recording all of them, why not parse the file?

Comment: Just in my resource folders - drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi etc

Answer (score 4):

You can use this

```
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("imageNameAsString", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```